# reading rows and columns from a textfile QT GUI C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read the size and the values of my matrix from a text file.
an example of a text file
graphe.txt

```
4 (the size of the matrix)
1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
```

I tried a code but unfortunately it didn't work .I got this errors:

```
error: 'class MainWindow' has no member named 'display' this->display->setText(val);
error: cannot convert 'QString' to 'int' in assignment
              matrice[ligne][i]=val;
```

---

```
 void MainWindow::remplir_matrice(int taille_mat,int matrice[][50] )
 {

  QFile file("/home/yosra/degré/degré/graphe.txt");
 if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
  { 
     QTextStream in(&file);
     int i=1;
     int ligne=1;
     while ((!in.atEnd())&&(ligne<=taille_mat))
        {
           ligne++;
          QString line = in.readLine();
          QStringList list = line.split(" ");
          QString val = list.at(i);
          this->display->setText(val);
          val.toInt();
          matrice[ligne][i]=val;
           i++;
        }
   file.close();
  }


 }
  void MainWindow::afficher(int matrice[][50],int taille_mat)
    {
      qDebug()<<" les elements de matrice";
      for(int i=0;i<taille_mat;i++)
       {
          for(int j=0;j<taille_mat;j++)
             qDebug()<<"M "<<matrice[i][j]<<endl;
       }
    }
 void MainWindow::parourir_fichier(int matrice[50][50],int taille_mat)

   {


    QFile file("/home/y/degré/classement/graphe.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
      {
         QTextStream in(&file);
         QStringList list;
         QString line = in.readLine();
         QString val = list.at(0);
         this->display->setText(val);
         val.toInt();
         taille_mat=val;
         qDebug() << "taille_mat=" << taille_mat<<endl;
         file.close();

     }
      remplir_matrice(taille_mat,matrice);
      afficher(matrice,taille_mat);


  }
```

### this is my MainWindow's header

```
  #include <QMainWindow>

  namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
               }

  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
      Q_OBJECT

    public:
     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
     void remplir_matrice(int taille_mat,int matrice[][50] );
     void parourir_fichier(int matrice[][50],int taille_mat);
     void afficher(int matrice[][50],int taille_mat);

    private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
     int matrice[50][50];
     int taille_mat;
  };
```

Comment: Post a `MainWindow`'s header file.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you mean:

```
ui->display->setText(val);
```

The `MainWindow` class does not have a pointer to the `display` object. Perhaps the `display` object was created with Qt Creator editor as a `TextEdit` field?

---

**Update**

If you just want to see a value while you are still developing your code, you are probably better off using `qDebug()` (documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdebug.html)). You will need to include  to make this work. The output will be shown in the output pane when you run the application from Qt Creator.

```
#include <QDebug>

// ...further down in your code:

qDebug() << "Output of val:" << val;
```

Comment: I found where that exists the problem. “display” is the name of the textbrowser of the my interface where I must display the contents of the file but for the moment I don't want to display its contents on the interface! I want to make a test to make sure that the values of the my matrix as its size seized in file.txt are quite affected .So I removed this instruction and the code now is compiled but unfortunately  when I carried out nothing is displayed on the console !!

Comment: @YosraHassad: that's the logical consequence: the code does not display anything. If you want to see something, you have to "put it out" somehow. The `setText()` method is not wrong for this purpose, you see it directly in your UI. However if you just want to print something you are probably better using `qDebug() << val;`

Comment: that is what I am doing. I used qDebug but it doesn't work (nothing is displayed in the console)

Comment: How do you launch the application?

Comment: QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

OTHER_FILES += \
    ../degré/classement/graphe.txt

Comment: @YosraHassad: This is the content of the project file. You need to start the application by clicking on the [green arrow button](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-writing-program.html#compiling-and-running-your-program), then look at the "application output" pane. You probably want to read [this documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-functions.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

The second error message is pretty clear, isn't it? A `QString` cannot be automatically converted to an `int`. I don't really know Qt, but a quick Google search reveals the existence of a [`toInt` member function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt), so the following probably works:

```
matrice[ligne][i]=val.toInt();
```

As for the first error message, `this->display` supposes the existence of a member *variable* in `MainWindow`. If `display` is a member *function* (it certainly sounds like one), then you need parentheses: `this->display()`. If there is no member function of that name either, then we cannot help you much with the code that you have posted.

Comment: Thanks i corrected the second error  but I still get the same error for "display" even if I add parentheses.

Comment: **What is `display`?**

Comment: @YosraHassad: The compiler tries to find a `display` member in `MainWindow`, but it does not find any. Since you have not shown us the definition of `MainWindow`, we cannot tell you what's wrong.